# Swift extension on NSManagedObject to return instancetype

Tags: swift

Say I have a managed object `Word`, and I want to be able to call

```
var w = Word.create(context)
```

So I've defined the following extension:

```
extension NSManagedObject {
    class func create(context:NSManagedObjectContext) -> NSManagedObject {
        var classname = NSStringFromClass(self)
        var object = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(classname, inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject
        return object
    }
}
```

However, it doesn't work as intended.

1. `NSStringFromClass` returns jibberish, like '_TtC8WordApp4Word', and I can't figure out a Swift equivalent
2. The return type is `NSManagedObject`, when it should be something like `Self`, but putting `Self` in there would not compile.

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding (1): Evan Swick has something about the mangled names: http://www.eswick.com/2014/06/inside-swift/

See [this answer][1] for a good explanation.

"_TtC8WordApp4Word": You would have to extract the last part of that string and use it for the `entityName` parameter.

Comment: Where's the answer with the good explanation?

Comment: @Emil seems to be deleted :-(

Answer (score 0):

The best way I have found so far is this, I still rather not have to pass the type to a function, but haven't been successful with that approach

```
extension NSManagedObject {

    class func create <T: NSManagedObject>(type: T.Type, context:NSManagedObjectContext) -> T {
        var classname = NSStringFromClass(type).pathExtension
        return NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(classname, inManagedObjectContext: context) as T
    }
}

NSManagedObject.create(Word.self, context:moc)
```

Comment: Here is a possible solution that does not require the type to be passed to the function: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27112385/1187415.

Comment: @MartinR Interesting when I tried that last time it wouldn't work. kept complaining that T is not the same type as Self