# Using Swift protocols with generics

Tags: core-data, swift, nsmanagedobject

I have a simple example that seems like it should work:

```
import CoreData

@objc protocol CoreDataModel {
    @optional class func entityName() -> String
}

class AbstractModel: NSManagedObject, CoreDataModel {
    class func create<T : CoreDataModel>(context:NSManagedObjectContext) -> T {
        var name = T.entityName?()
        var object = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(name, inManagedObjectContext: context) as T
        return object
    }
}
```

So we have a class called `AbstractModel` which conforms to the protocol `CoreDataModel`, and `CoreDataModel` defines an optional class method called `entityName`.

However, this line:

```
var name = T.entityName?()
```

causes the error:

> Expected member name or constructor call after type name

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

#### Edit

Removing the word `@optional` from the declaration and changing the function a bit allows the code to compile, but now I get a runtime error saying that the

> 'Swift dynamic cast failed'

```
@objc protocol CoreDataModel {
     class func entityName() -> String
}

class AbstractModel: NSManagedObject, CoreDataModel {
    
    class func entityName() -> String {
        return "AbstractModel"
    }

    class func create<T : CoreDataModel>(aClass:T.Type, context:NSManagedObjectContext) -> T {
        var name = aClass.entityName()
        var object = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(name, inManagedObjectContext: context) as T
        return object
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you do this to get around the issue you were having here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24832955/84783. Because I'm having a similar problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot explain why your code causes a runtime exception. But it works if you change
the function prototype

```
class func create<T : CoreDataModel>(aClass:T.Type, context:NSManagedObjectContext) -> T
```

to

```
class func create<T : NSManagedObject where T: CoreDataModel>(aClass:T.Type, context:NSManagedObjectContext) -> T
```

Assuming that your managed object subclass conforms to the protocol, for example

```
extension Event : CoreDataModel {
    class func entityName() -> String {
        return "Event"
    }
}
```

then this works and creates a new object:

```
let newManagedObject = AbstractModel.create(Event.self, context: context)
```

---

Alternatively, you could use the approach from the answer to
"[Swift: return Array of type self](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24537238/swift-return-array-of-type-self)" and
define an extension to the `NSManagedObjectContext` class:

```
extension NSManagedObjectContext {
    func create<T : NSManagedObject where T : CoreDataModel >(entity: T.Type) -> T {
        var classname = entity.entityName()
        var object = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(classname, inManagedObjectContext: self) as T
        return object
    }
}
```

Then a new object would be created as

```
let newManagedObject = context.create(Event.self)
```

Comment: So what was the problem, that it was casting an object to CoreDataModel, which is a protocol?

Comment: Hey Martin, is this still the ideal example? I'm looking at using this so I can use the entity with a generic repository (a la data mapper instead of active record). Any thoughts as I'm planning on using this, but in swift 4.

Answer (score -4):

From "The Swift Programming Language"

> Because T is a placeholder, Swift does not look for an actual type called T.

As T is not a real type, it is maybe not useful to cast to T.

Comment: "As T is not a real type, you cannot cast to T." You *can* cast to `T`.

Comment: OK, but it is still very probable that this is the cast that crashes the program.

Comment: generic is about casting to placeholder