# Swift and Core-Data, class type as a parameter

Tags: swift, core-data

Working with Swift and Core-Data, I have the following function, which is useful to insert a new record in an entity:

```
func insertObject (entityName: String, dico: NSDictionary) {
    var newItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(entityName, inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext!) as! EventList

    for (key, value) in dico {
        newItem.setValue(value, forKey: key as! String)
    }

    var error : NSError? = nil
    managedObjectContext!.save(&error)
}
```

Though it works, there is one problem: the type "EventList" is hard-coded in the function and that is not good if I want the function for general use.
Ideally I would like to pass a parameter: type to the function and then use it instead of "EventList".

Is that possible and how? What I have found on the net seems not clear and at the limit of my present Swift knowledge.

=== Update after further experiment ===

Following some advice I got from feed backs and after taking a look at how generics work, I remade my function as follows:

```
func insertObject <T:NSManagedObject> (entityName:String,dico:NSDictionary) {
    var newItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(entityName, inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext!) as! T
    for (key, value) in dico {
        newItem.setValue(value, forKey: key as! String)
    }

    var error : NSError? = nil
    managedObjectContext!.save(&error)
}
```

I didn't get any error on a particular line of code, but got the following big error-message in the issue navigator:

> CompileSwift normal armv7
>   /Users/abcxyz/Documents/iOS/LibBin/Swift_CoreDataBox/CoreDataBox.swift
>       cd /Users/abcxyz/Documents/iOS/MyAp
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift
>   -frontend -c -primary-file /Users/abcxyz/Documents/iOS/LibBin/Swift_CoreDataBox/CoreDataBox.swift
>   /Users/abcxyz/Documents/iOS/MyAp/MyAp/RootViewController.swift
>   /Users/abcxyz/Documents/iOS/MyAp/MyAp/ModelController.swift
>   /Users/abcxyz/Documents/iOS/MyAp/MyAp/DataViewController.swift
>   /Users/abcxyz/Documents/iOS/MyAp/MyAp/MyAp.swift
>   /Users/abcxyz/Documents/iOS/MyAp/MyAp/AppDelegate.swift
>   /Users/abcxyz/Documents/iOS/MyAp/MyAp/DataInput_ViewController.swift
>   -target armv7-apple-ios7.1 -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk
>   -I /Users/abcxyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyAp-ehmiuzpyuhwbkpfvduswfbhkdjut/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
>   -F /Users/abcxyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyAp-ehmiuzpyuhwbkpfvduswfbhkdjut/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
>   -g -module-cache-path /Users/abcxyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache
>   -serialize-debugging-options -Xcc -I/Users/abcxyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyAp-ehmiuzpyuhwbkpfvduswfbhkdjut/Build/Intermediates/MyAp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyAp.build/swift-overrides.hmap
>   -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/abcxyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyAp-ehmiuzpyuhwbkpfvduswfbhkdjut/Build/Intermediates/MyAp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyAp.build/MyAp-generated-files.hmap
>   -Xcc -I/Users/abcxyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyAp-ehmiuzpyuhwbkpfvduswfbhkdjut/Build/Intermediates/MyAp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyAp.build/MyAp-own-target-headers.hmap
>   -Xcc -I/Users/abcxyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyAp-ehmiuzpyuhwbkpfvduswfbhkdjut/Build/Intermediates/MyAp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyAp.build/MyAp-all-target-headers.hmap
>   -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/abcxyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyAp-ehmiuzpyuhwbkpfvduswfbhkdjut/Build/Intermediates/MyAp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyAp.build/MyAp-project-headers.hmap
>   -Xcc -I/Users/abcxyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyAp-ehmiuzpyuhwbkpfvduswfbhkdjut/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/include
>   -Xcc -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
>   -Xcc -I/Users/abcxyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyAp-ehmiuzpyuhwbkpfvduswfbhkdjut/Build/Intermediates/MyAp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyAp.build/DerivedSources/armv7
>   -Xcc -I/Users/abcxyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyAp-ehmiuzpyuhwbkpfvduswfbhkdjut/Build/Intermediates/MyAp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyAp.build/DerivedSources
>   -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc -working-directory/Users/abcxyz/Documents/iOS/MyAp -emit-module-doc-path /Users/abcxyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyAp-ehmiuzpyuhwbkpfvduswfbhkdjut/Build/Intermediates/MyAp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyAp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CoreDataBox~partial.swiftdoc -Onone -module-name Me -emit-module-path /Users/abcxyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyAp-ehmiuzpyuhwbkpfvduswfbhkdjut/Build/Intermediates/MyAp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyAp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CoreDataBox~partial.swiftmodule
>   -serialize-diagnostics-path /Users/abcxyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyAp-ehmiuzpyuhwbkpfvduswfbhkdjut/Build/Intermediates/MyAp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyAp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CoreDataBox.dia
>   -emit-dependencies-path /Users/abcxyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyAp-ehmiuzpyuhwbkpfvduswfbhkdjut/Build/Intermediates/MyAp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyAp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CoreDataBox.d
>   -emit-reference-dependencies-path /Users/abcxyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyAp-ehmiuzpyuhwbkpfvduswfbhkdjut/Build/Intermediates/MyAp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyAp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CoreDataBox.swiftdeps
>   -o /Users/abcxyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyAp-ehmiuzpyuhwbkpfvduswfbhkdjut/Build/Intermediates/MyAp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyAp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CoreDataBox.o
>
> 0  swift                    0x00000001007e92b8
>   llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(__sFILE*) + 40 1  swift
>   0x00000001007e9794 SignalHandler(int) + 452 2 
>   libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff96272f1a _sigtramp + 26 3 
>   libsystem_platform.dylib 0x7994a32ea448635d _sigtramp + 237057117 4 
>   swift                    0x000000010016c076
>   swift::irgen::emitPolymorphicArguments(swift::irgen::IRGenFunction&,
>   swift::CanTypeWrapper,
>   swift::CanTypeWrapper,
>   llvm::ArrayRef, swift::irgen::Explosion&) + 630 5
>   swift                    0x00000001001b6d0f
>   swift::SILVisitor<(anonymous namespace)::IRGenSILFunction,
>   void>::visit(swift::ValueBase*) + 40287 6  swift
>   0x00000001001ac39d
>   swift::irgen::IRGenModule::emitSILFunction(swift::SILFunction*) + 9901
>   7  swift                    0x0000000100116f4f
>   swift::irgen::IRGenModule::emitGlobalTopLevel() + 159 8  swift
>   0x0000000100196c59 performIRGeneration(swift::IRGenOptions&,
>   swift::Module*, swift::SILModule*, llvm::StringRef,
>   llvm::LLVMContext&, swift::SourceFile*, unsigned int) + 2121 9  swift 
>   0x0000000100197693 swift::performIRGeneration(swift::IRGenOptions&,
>   swift::SourceFile&, swift::SILModule*, llvm::StringRef,
>   llvm::LLVMContext&, unsigned int) + 51 10 swift
>   0x00000001000d3087 frontend_main(llvm::ArrayRef, char
>   const*, void*) + 6647 11 swift                    0x00000001000d14e6
>   main + 1814 12 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff947a35c9 start + 1
>   13 libdyld.dylib            0x0000000000000041 start + 1803930233
>   Stack dump:
>   0.    Program arguments: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift
>   -frontend -c -primary-file /Users/abcxyz/Documents/iOS/LibBin/Swift_CoreDataBox/CoreDataBox.swift
>   /Users/abcxyz/Documents/iOS/MyAp/MyAp/RootViewController.swift
>   /Users/abcxyz/Documents/iOS/MyAp/MyAp/ModelController.swift
>   /Users/abcxyz/Documents/iOS/MyAp/MyAp/DataViewController.swift
>   /Users/abcxyz/Documents/iOS/MyAp/MyAp/MyAp.swift
>   /Users/abcxyz/Documents/iOS/MyAp/MyAp/AppDelegate.swift
>   /Users/abcxyz/Documents/iOS/MyAp/MyAp/DataInput_ViewController.swift
>   -target armv7-apple-ios7.1 -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk
>   -I /Users/abcxyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyAp-ehmiuzpyuhwbkpfvduswfbhkdjut/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
>   -F /Users/abcxyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyAp-ehmiuzpyuhwbkpfvduswfbhkdjut/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
>   -g -module-cache-path /Users/abcxyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache
>   -serialize-debugging-options -Xcc -I/Users/abcxyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyAp-ehmiuzpyuhwbkpfvduswfbhkdjut/Build/Intermediates/MyAp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyAp.build/swift-overrides.hmap
>   -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/abcxyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyAp-ehmiuzpyuhwbkpfvduswfbhkdjut/Build/Intermediates/MyAp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyAp.build/MyAp-generated-files.hmap
>   -Xcc -I/Users/abcxyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyAp-ehmiuzpyuhwbkpfvduswfbhkdjut/Build/Intermediates/MyAp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyAp.build/MyAp-own-target-headers.hmap
>   -Xcc -I/Users/abcxyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyAp-ehmiuzpyuhwbkpfvduswfbhkdjut/Build/Intermediates/MyAp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyAp.build/MyAp-all-target-headers.hmap
>   -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/abcxyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyAp-ehmiuzpyuhwbkpfvduswfbhkdjut/Build/Intermediates/MyAp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyAp.build/MyAp-project-headers.hmap
>   -Xcc -I/Users/abcxyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyAp-ehmiuzpyuhwbkpfvduswfbhkdjut/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/include
>   -Xcc -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
>   -Xcc -I/Users/abcxyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyAp-ehmiuzpyuhwbkpfvduswfbhkdjut/Build/Intermediates/MyAp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyAp.build/DerivedSources/armv7
>   -Xcc -I/Users/abcxyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyAp-ehmiuzpyuhwbkpfvduswfbhkdjut/Build/Intermediates/MyAp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyAp.build/DerivedSources
>   -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc -working-directory/Users/abcxyz/Documents/iOS/MyAp -emit-module-doc-path /Users/abcxyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyAp-ehmiuzpyuhwbkpfvduswfbhkdjut/Build/Intermediates/MyAp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyAp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CoreDataBox~partial.swiftdoc -Onone -module-name Me -emit-module-path /Users/abcxyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyAp-ehmiuzpyuhwbkpfvduswfbhkdjut/Build/Intermediates/MyAp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyAp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CoreDataBox~partial.swiftmodule
>   -serialize-diagnostics-path /Users/abcxyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyAp-ehmiuzpyuhwbkpfvduswfbhkdjut/Build/Intermediates/MyAp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyAp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CoreDataBox.dia
>   -emit-dependencies-path /Users/abcxyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyAp-ehmiuzpyuhwbkpfvduswfbhkdjut/Build/Intermediates/MyAp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyAp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CoreDataBox.d
>   -emit-reference-dependencies-path /Users/abcxyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyAp-ehmiuzpyuhwbkpfvduswfbhkdjut/Build/Intermediates/MyAp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyAp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CoreDataBox.swiftdeps
>   -o /Users/abcxyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyAp-ehmiuzpyuhwbkpfvduswfbhkdjut/Build/Intermediates/MyAp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyAp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CoreDataBox.o
>
> 1. While emitting IR SIL function @_TToFC2Me11CoreDataBox12insertObjectfS0_U__FTSS4dicoCSo12NSDictionary_T_
>      for 'insertObject' at
>      /Users/abcxyz/Documents/iOS/LibBin/Swift_CoreDataBox/CoreDataBox.swift:98:5

Comment: That's probably a good advice, how do I do that?
Is it easy (simple)?

Comment: Don't have a compiler right now but it should be something along the lines `func insertObject<T>(entityName: String, dictionary: NSDictionary` and when you force cast it to an `EventList` cast it to `T` instead.

Comment: This is best - http://swift.oz-apps.com/2015/04/creating-a-class-from-a-string-in-swift/

Comment: Seems unnecessary to me. Will `T` accept the `setValue` method without further casting?

Comment: Sorry I'm on mobile and not of great help here but take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24839064/1489885). This should put you in the right direction.

Comment: @Mundi Fair point ;)

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I am looking at generics and how to use them. It is very interesting and seems similar to what I used to know as function templates. I don't know if the implementation is similar though.

Comment: I also started to read about Generics and updated my question to reflect the current state of my issue, with a new function I made. At this point I got a huge error message and I do not quite know whether I am navigating into difficult waters of if I just made some beginner mistake somewhere.

Comment: Maybe you should just use my suggestion and move on. You can always post a new question with your "academic" issue.

Comment: You are right, though at this point my problem is still there not solved. I received advice helping me to move forward, but no solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

You are just using KVC to set the attributes, so *you do not need* a specific `NSManagedObject` subclass.

Substituting the cast with one to `NSManagedObject` should work. Making it generic (in the Swift sense) would be overkill - after all, you need the `NSManagedObject`. So you are "generalizing" rather than using "generics".

Comment: If I leave out the cast, commenting out "as! EventList", I get a compiler  warning: Variable ‘newItem’ inferred to have type ‘AnyObject’, which may be unexpected.
And I suppose that is not good.

Comment: @Michel: In that case `as! NSManagedObject` should to the trick.

Comment: Right, I thought that was obvious. Thanks Martin.

Comment: Yes, that does (partly) the trick; no more compiler warning. But, there is another issue down the road, when executing the function, I get this message:

CoreData: warning: Unable to load class named 'PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME.MyEntity’ for entity 'MyEntity'.  Class not found, using default NSManagedObject instead.

As a trial if I replace NSManagedObject by MyEntity (which is what I do not want to do), the message disappears.

Comment: If you need to use a subclass you need to cast again. Seems to work alright.

Comment: Yes, but how can I do that without having to hard code this subclass name? In other words in this case how do I pass "MyEntity"?