# How can I create instances of managed object subclasses in a NSManagedObject Swift extension?

Tags: swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

When creating an extension helper to `NSManagedObject` to create a new managed object subclass, swift provides the `Self` type to mimic `instancetype` which is great, but i can't seem to typecast from `AnyObject`. The below code does not compile with error **'AnyObject' is not convertible to 'Self'**

Help?

```
extension NSManagedObject
{
    class func createInContext(context:NSManagedObjectContext) -> Self {
        var classname = className()
        var object: AnyObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(classname, inManagedObjectContext: context)
        return object
    }


    class func className() -> String {
        let classString = NSStringFromClass(self)
        //Remove Swift module name
        let range = classString.rangeOfString(".", options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch, range: Range<String.Index>(start:classString.startIndex, end: classString.endIndex), locale: nil)
        return classString.substringFromIndex(range!.endIndex)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

*(Updated for Swift 3/4 now. Solutions for earlier Swift versions
can be found in the edit history.)*

You can use `unsafeDowncast` to cast the return value
of `NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject()` to `Self`
(which is the type on which the method is actually called):

```
extension NSManagedObject {
    class func create(in context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> Self {
        let classname = entityName()
        let object = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: classname, into: context)
        return unsafeDowncast(object, to: self)
    }

    // Returns the unqualified class name, i.e. the last component.
    // Can be overridden in a subclass.
    class func entityName() -> String {
        return String(describing: self)
    }
}
```

Then

```
let obj = YourEntity.createInContext(context)
```

works and the compiler infers the type of `obj` correctly as `YourEntity`.

Comment: 2¢: That generic function is a pretty good use case for the `private` keyword.

Comment: In Swift 2, split isn't a global function anymore. We can use classString.componentsSeparatedByString(".") instead.

Comment: @JonathanZhan: You are right, I'll update it. Thanks.

Comment: @ambientlight: You are completely right. I used that in the "alternative approach" posted separately below.

Comment: @MartinR great explanation. But I am not able to understand why func createInContext<T>(context:NSManagedObjectContext, type : T.Type) -> T  needs 'type' argument? Cant type of 'T' be inferred by the return type of caller function? #newToSwift :)

Comment: @VishalSingh: You are right, that works! – But note that a much simpler solution exists, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/33583941/1187415 below.

Comment: @MartinR thank you for the clarification. I have seen the solution you mentioned and it works great, but I was just clearing my doubt on this one.

Comment: I believe one could potentially use [unsafeBitCast(object, self)](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_StandardLibrary_Functions/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/func/s:Fs13unsafeBitCastu0_rFTxMq__q_) instead of writing one's own helper func.  Just a thought.

Comment: @KickimusButticus: You are right, that works here as well. But note that a simpler solution exists, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/33583941/1187415 below.

Answer (score 11):

Here is a different approach to solve the problem, by implementing
an *initializer* method (tested with Xcode 7.1):

```
extension NSManagedObject {

    // Returns the unqualified class name, i.e. the last component.
    // Can be overridden in a subclass.
    class func entityName() -> String {
        return String(self)
    }

    convenience init(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        let eName = self.dynamicType.entityName()
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName(eName, inManagedObjectContext: context)!
        self.init(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
    }
}
```

Init methods have an implicit return type of `Self` and no casting
tricks are necessary.

```
let obj = YourEntity(context: context)
```

creates an object of the `YourEntity` type.

---

**Swift 3/4 update:**

```
extension NSManagedObject {

    // Returns the unqualified class name, i.e. the last component.
    // Can be overridden in a subclass.
    class func entityName() -> String {
        return String(describing: self)
    }

    convenience init(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        let eName = type(of: self).entityName()
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: eName, in: context)!
        self.init(entity: entity, insertInto: context)
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work when `YourEntity` is defined in ObjC - `init` from the extension isn't called in tests - works perfectly when Swift is being used

Comment: Actually, it works with `YourEntity` implemented in ObjC if method argument isn't exactly the same as in overridden constructor - e.g. `convenience init(usedContext: NSManagedObjectContext)` definition and calling `let entity = YourEntity(usedContext: context)` works just fine

Comment: @KrzysztofSkrzynecki: Thank you for the feedback! – The `init(context:)` constructor was introduced with iOS 10, it did not exist when I wrote the initial version of this answer.

Answer (score 4):

In Swift 2 there is a very smart solution using a protocol and a protocol extension

```
protocol Fetchable
{
  typealias FetchableType: NSManagedObject

  static var entityName : String { get }
  static func createInContext(context: NSManagedObjectContext) ->  FetchableType
}

extension Fetchable where Self : NSManagedObject, FetchableType == Self
{
  static func createInContext(context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> FetchableType
  {
    return NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(entityName, inManagedObjectContext: context) as! FetchableType
  }
}
```

In each `NSManagedObject` subclass add the protocol `Fetchable` and implement the property `entityName`.

Now the function `MyEntity.createInContext(…)` will return the proper type without further type casting.