# Type methods ignoring global scope?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am trying to write a convenience method for creating new object types in CoreData. I have my `managedObjectContext` defined at global level in another file.

This is what my code looks like:

```
class Room: NSManagedObject {

    class func createNew() -> NSManagedObject {
        return NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Room", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!) as? NSManagedObject
    }
}
```

Where I am calling `managedObjectContext` I get an error. It says

> Room.Type does not have a property named managedObjectContext

Yet that is not where I want to look for this data. It even appears in the auto-complete correctly and then only breaks after completing.

Comment: This might also interest you in this context: [How can I create instances of managed object subclasses in a NSManagedObject Swift extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27109268/how-can-i-create-instances-of-managed-object-subclasses-in-a-nsmanagedobject-swi).

Comment: That is great. That is actually exactly what I was wanting to do, but was in the process of figuring it out for myself. Thanks for the shortcut :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `NSMangedObject` has an *instance property* 
with the same name `managedObjectContext` (which you of course cannot
access from a type method).

Renaming the global variable should solve the problem, or you can
refer to it with the explicit module name of your app:

```
YourAppModuleName.managedObjectContext
```

Comment: You are welcome! – Actually I don't know if this is not a bug in the compiler, so you might consider to file a bug report.