# Protocol for class method

Tags: swift

I want to declare in a protocol a `class func`, I intend to conform to this protocol from a class A, B and C.

B and C inherit from A.

Essentially I want to override this func in B and C while still providing an implementation in A.

So, I had to declare my protocol as follows:

```
protocol MyManagedObjectCoolStuff {

    static func entityName() -> String
}
```

And then I have this in A:

```
class A: NSManagedObject { }

class B: A { }

class C: A { }

extension A: MyManagedObjectCoolStuff {

  static func entityName() -> String {
        return "Animal"
    }
}

extension B: MyManagedObjectCoolStuff {

   override static func entityName() -> String {
        return "Bat"
    }
}

extension C: MyManagedObjectCoolStuff {

   override static func entityName() -> String {
        return "Cat"
    }
}
```

The problem here, is clear and Xcode confirms: "Class method overrides a 'final' class method".

[image]

How can I work around this? I cannot use `class func` in the protocol... I'm not sure how to abstract this.

Thanks!

Comment: remove `override static` at B and C, there cannot be two implementations of a static function

Comment: Alternatively, don't make B and C inherit from A.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In a *class* definition, `static` is an alias for `class final`,
so it marks a type method (or property) which cannot be overridden
in subclasses.

Since you *want* to override the method in subclasses,
all you have to do is to define the method as `class` instead of `static`:

```
extension A: MyManagedObjectCoolStuff {

    class func entityName() -> String {
        return "Animal"
    }
}

extension B: MyManagedObjectCoolStuff {

    override class func entityName() -> String {
        return "Bat"
    }
}

extension C: MyManagedObjectCoolStuff {

    override class func entityName() -> String {
        return "Cat"
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively one could use the fact that for a Core Data entity,
the class name is *usually* defined as `<ModuleName>.<EntityName>`
so that the entity name is the last component of the class name.

So you could define `entityName()` as an
extension method of `NSManagedObject` (the superclass of all Core Data
object classes) as in [How can I create instances of managed object subclasses in a NSManagedObject Swift extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27109268/how-can-i-create-instances-of-managed-object-subclasses-in-a-nsmanagedobject-swi):

```
extension NSManagedObject {

    class func entityName() -> String {
        let classString = NSStringFromClass(self)
        // The entity is the last component of dot-separated class name:
        let components = split(classString) { $0 == "." }
        return components.last ?? classString
    }
}
```

and override it only where necessary:

```
class A: NSManagedObject { }

class B: A { }

class C: A { }

extension C {

    override class func entityName() -> String {
        return "Cat"
    }
}

println(A.entityName()) // A
println(B.entityName()) // B
println(C.entityName()) // Cat
```

Comment: @MatteoPiombo: Thanks for the edit suggestion, but my intention was to show that the problem can be solved using the extension methods from the question. Defining `class func entityName()` directly in `class A` (as in your now deleted answer) *might* be appropriate, but seems unrelated to the problem to me. Another problem with that approach is that NSManagedObject subclasses can be auto-generated from Xcode.

Comment: ... and thinking about your suggestion again led to the "addendum" :)