# Get the class type that implements a protocol swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, protocols

So what I am trying to do is make it easy for me to implement many custom UITableViewCells on one tableView, to do this I wanted to create a protocol that would facilitate filling out the function:

```
- (void)registerClass:(nullable Class)cellClass forCellReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
```

my protocol so far looks like this:

```
protocol TableViewCellClassReportingProtocol: class {
    func reuseID() -> String
}

extension TableViewCellClassReportingProtocol {
    static func classObject() -> AnyClass? {
        return self.class
    }
}
```

however I am having issues with getting the class type even thought I specify that this protocol must be implemented by a class. Any suggestions, I may be approaching this the wrong way

Comment: have you tried self.dynamicType?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this was close to the right answar and let me both elaborate and give credit to Charles A.

dynamicType is part of the answar! great call!

the function implamintation also had to change, because of subclassing and static really meaning "class final"

[Protocol for class method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31113488/protocol-for-class-method)

the override points must be

```
override class func reuseID() -> String
```