# class function with generic return value

Tags: swift

Right now I have the following classes:

```
class A {
    class func instantiate() -> A {
        return MakeObject()
    }
}

class B: A {}

let x = B.instantiate()
```

This results in x being of type A. How can I change `instantiate` in order to return an instance of the subclass that was called from? In other words, so that x ends up being of type B.

EDIT:

This is what I used to solve it, based on Martin R's answers:

```
class A {
    class func instantiate() -> Self {
        func helper<T>() -> T {
            return MakeObject() as! T
        }

        return helper()
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you define an `init` method instead? That would avoid the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The returns type needs to be `Self` (which is the concrete type when
the class method is called), and initialization must be done with a
`required init` method (which can be overridden in a subclass):

```
class A {

    class func instantiate() -> Self {
        return self.init()
    }

    required init() {

    }
}

class B: A {}

let x = B.instantiate() // `x` has type `B`
```

Alternatively, just define an init method

```
init(parameters ...) {

}
```

which "automatically" returns instances of the class that is is
called on.

Comment: It may well be that this solution has been given before, but I haven't found an exact duplicate yet. Please let me know if this is a duplicate, then I'll delete the answer and link to the existing answer instead.

Comment: even thought it could be a duplicate, i like you answer. it is very useful!

Comment: Thanks, this is useful. How about if I wanted to return an object without using `init` though (e.g. from a cache)? Using something like `return obj as! Self` is not allowed.

Comment: @NickKeets: The approach from http://stackoverflow.com/a/31167323/1187415 might work.