# Getting the actual type from a generic return type

Tags: ios, swift, generics, uiview, xib

I am having an extension on a `UIView` that loads a nib of a certain type and name:

```
extension UIView {

    class func fromNib<T : UIView>() -> T? {

        guard let nib = Bundle(for: T.self).loadNibNamed(String(describing: T.self), owner: nil, options: nil)?[0]
            else {
                return nil
        }
        return nib as? T
    }
}
```

Now in my `Hint` class (which is a subclass of a `UIView`) I use the above extension like this:

```
 if let view = Hint.fromNib(){
        self.addSubview(view)
        view.frame = self.bounds         
 }
```

This doesn't work because the result of `T.self` is always UIView even if a Hint is class on what `fromNib` method is called. If I try to hardcode a class like this:

```
Bundle(for: Hint.self).loadNibNamed(String(describing: Hint.self), owner: nil, options: nil)
```

then everything works. How to get a type name of a class on which `fromNib()` method is actually called ?

Here is my Hint class:

```
class Hint:UIView {

     required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        if let view = UIView.fromNib(){
            self.addSubview(view)
            view.frame = self.bounds

        }

    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        if let view = UIView.fromNib(){
            self.addSubview(view)
            view.frame = self.bounds
        }
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        if let view = UIView.fromNib(){
            self.addSubview(view)
            view.frame = self.bounds
        }
    }

}
```

So everything is very simple. A nib file has only one label and one image view, but I guess that is pretty much irrelevant for the current issue.

Comment: Try `let hint: Hint = UIView.fromNib()`. I ran into the same issue.

Comment: Have you tried to define the type before calling the method? i.e. `if let view: Hint = Hint.fromNib()`

Comment: Oops.. Emilio beat me by 10 seconds

Comment: @EmilioPelaez I just tried that, so now it doesn't crash, but the view loaded from a nib is not visible (with the code I have provided)... Have to put some breakpoints ...

Comment: @Whirlwind I elaborated on an answer. I think using `Hint?` might be better, but my method didn't use optionals so I haven't tried it.

Comment: @MichaelFourre I have added my Hint class as well. Currently, if I do something like `if let view:Hint = UIView.fromNib()...` the content of a nib doesn't show up neither at runtime, nor at design time (in a storyboard)...

Comment: By using something like `let hint:Hint? = UIView.fromNib()` the `hint` end up as nil.

Comment: Perhaps you can use this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31167323/1187415.

Comment: @MartinR If I load it from a main bundle, like from your example, I have an error saying : *... Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhone‌​Simulator.platform/D‌​eveloper/Library/Xco‌​de/Overlays> (loaded)' with name 'Hint' "*. That's why I am using `Bundle(for:)` method. Also I've tried to change your code to use `Bundle(for:)` method, but I got the same results - a nib is not loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to know the type of the class `fromNib()` is called on, which is `self` within a class method:

```
extension UIView {
    class func fromNib<T : UIView>() -> T? {
        guard
            let nibs = Bundle(for: self).loadNibNamed(String(describing: self), owner: nil, options: nil),
            let nib = nibs.first
            else {
                return nil
        }

        return nib as? T
    }
}
```

The following:

```
if let viewFromXib = MyXib.fromNib(){            
    view.addSubview(viewFromXib)
    viewFromXib.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30))
    print(viewFromXib)
}
```

works and prints:

```
<TESTS.MyXib: 0x7f9531408aa0; frame = (0 0; 30 30); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x60000002b8e0>>
```

I do not really understand how the return type `T` is inferred though.

---

Update:

I was digging in how the return type `T` is inferred and the answer is: It doesn't.

This:

```
class func fromNib() -> UIView? {
    guard
        let nibs = Bundle(for: self).loadNibNamed(String(describing: self), owner: nil, options: nil),
        let nib = nibs.first
        else {
            return nil
    }

    return nib as? UIView
}
```

is equivalent.

So even this answer is solving the issue, it does not answer the question.

Comment: Thanks! Good question also!

Comment: Updated the answer with more (maybe shallow) thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the exact same issue with the exact same method, even named it the same. I was unable to use the current class type because the compiler assumes it's `UIView` instead of it's subclasses.

What happens is that `Hint.fromNib()` ends up being the exact same as `UIView.fromNib()`, since `T` doesn't depend on the class it's being called on, so `T` is inferred to be a `UIView`. What you have to do is to help the compiler infer the correct type by specifying what kind of view you expect to get.

`let hint: Hint? = UIView.fromNib()`

I would add that while you are correctly using `guard`, `first` is safer than `[0]`, so I would change your method to look like this:

```
let bundle = Bundle(for: T.self)
let nib = bundle.loadNibNamed(String(describing: T.self), owner: nil, options: nil)
guard let view = nib?.first as? T else {
  return nil
}
return view
```

Comment: Okay, I will try your code as well. Also, this line, `let bundle = Bundle(for: T.self)` won't compile. An explicit cast to AnyClass is required ... Compiler suggest this : `let bundle = Bundle(for: T.self as! AnyClass)`

Comment: Sadly, the same results. I only get desired results, which are 1) having contents of a nib loaded into my custom view and rendered at design time (visible in storyboard) ,and 2) loaded at runtime of course, if I hardcode `Hint.self` instead of `T.self`

Comment: I have added an implementation of my Hint class... I hope it can be useful in  solving this.