# Generic Return Type Based on Class

Tags: swift, generics, factory

I'm trying to create factory method on a class that automatically casts to the class it's on.

```
extension NSObject {
    // how can I get the return type to be the current NSObject subclass
    // instead of NSObject?
    class func create() -> NSObject {
        return self.init()
    }

    // example: create(type: NSArray.self)
    class func create<T:NSObject>(type:T.Type) -> T {
        return T()
    }
}
```

Example two works, but gets NO advantage from being a class method:

```
let result = NSArray.create(type: NSArray.self)
```

But I'd love to be able to just call:

```
let result = NSArray.create()
```

without having to cast afterwards. Is there a way to do this in Swift?

Comment: ...you mean like an initializer?

Comment: @Noah yes in this boiled down example, an init would work fine, but I'm actually never calling the init myself. That's just for exposition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the class-level `Self` for this:

```
extension NSObject {
    class func create() -> Self {
        return self.init()
    }
}

let array = NSArray.create()
```

But I don't really see why you would, since you might as well just add an initializer.

Comment: Thanks, thought I had tried that. This is useful for `NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject` and that kind of thing. So this question is complete and I'll accept this answer. Beyond this: I need to get from my generic `NSManagedObject` to `Self` and forcing an `as!` downcast doesn't work. Hmmmm....

Comment: @DanRosenstark Compare [Return instancetype in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33200035/2976878)

Comment: @Hamish fascinating, I don't really understand the type inference but I did manage to create a working example.

Comment: Thanks @Hamish and Noah. Noah I've accepted your answer but you can see my answer below and what I was shooting for (without knowing to specify it, of course).

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer does the trick, thanks!

However, I needed this for a case where I wasn't calling the `init` directly. Instead, I had an object that was of type `NSObject` and needed a forced downcast

As @Hamish pointed out from [this other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31167323/8047), you can use the generic inference on a class method if you're another layer deep (a method called by a class method).

```
class func create() -> Self {
    return createInner()
}

class func createInner<T>() -> T {
    // upcasting to NSObject to show that we can downcast
    let b = self.init() as NSObject
    return b  as! T
}

let array = NSArray.create() // gives me an NSArray
```

---

### An Example with CoreData

I still can't figure out how to get the `fetch` part to compile, so I'm using an external function still.

```
import CoreData

// callers use
// try fetch(type: SomeMO.self, moc: moc)
func fetch<T:NSManagedObject>(type:T.Type, moc:NSManagedObjectContext) throws -> [T] {
    return try T.fetch(moc: moc) as! [T]
}

extension NSManagedObject {
    class func makeOne(moc:NSManagedObjectContext) -> Self {
        return makeOneInner(moc: moc)
    }

    private class func makeOneInner<T>(moc:NSManagedObjectContext) -> T {
        let name = "\(self)"
        let retVal = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: name, into: moc)
        return retVal as! T
    }

    class func fetch(moc:NSManagedObjectContext) throws -> [NSManagedObject] {
        let fetchReq:NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject> = self.fetchRequest() as! NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>
        let retVal = try moc.fetch(fetchReq) as [NSManagedObject]
        return retVal
    }
}
```