# Swift Generic Function

Tags: ios, swift, macos, generics

I'm trying to create a Generic function in a class extension, but I get compiler error.

I have too classes A and B, both extending `NSManagedObject`

I want to create a `findOne()` function in my class extension.

```
extension NSManagedObject {
    public class func findOne() -> NSManagedObject {
    // some working stuff returning a NSManagedObject
    }
}
```

My problem is : When I use this method on A, the return type is `NSManagedObject`

```
let aObject = A.findOne //type is NSManagedObject
```

So, obviously I can cast it and get an A-class object

```
let aObject = A.findOne as! A//type is NSManagedObject
```

Starting here, I want to replace my extension implementation to use generic, making me have :

```
let aObject = A.findOne //type is A
```

I tried this :

```
extension NSManagedObject {
     public class func findOne<T>() -> T {
     // some working stuff returning a NSManagedObject
     }
}
```

But `A.findOne()` is still `NSManagedObject` type.

Can anyone help me ?

**UPDATE**
The Following code is actually working if I use :

```
 class func findOne<T : NSManagedObject>() -> T {
    //Do some stuff
   return myObject as! T
 }

let myObject : A = A.findOne()
```

Comment: you might want to use `Self` as return type.

Comment: Compare [How can I create instances of managed object subclasses in a NSManagedObject Swift extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27109268/how-can-i-create-instances-of-managed-object-subclasses-in-a-nsmanagedobject-swi).

Comment: @Alessandro: Why did you add "OS X" in the title and the tags? Core Data exists on iOS as well, and nothing in this question is specific to OS X.

Comment: @Martin R  NSManagedObject exist on both iOS and OSX , i want to add just only on the tag. On title is my wrong specification.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `BaseModel`, which all your models inherit from. Use the generic type parameter to cast the object accordingly

```
class BaseModel : NSManagedObject {

    class func find<T>(objectID: NSManagedObjectID) -> T
    {
        return someObjectContext.objectWithID(objectID) as! T
    }
}

class Person : BaseModel {

}


let person: Person = Person.find(someObjectId)
```

[Generics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html)

Comment: Both A and B are extending `NSManagedObject` so your answer does not resolve my problem :(