# Class function returning Self? for Core Data abstract class

Tags: swift, inheritance, core-data, return-type, introspection

I have a Core Data class `List` inheriting from abstract type `Synchronizable`. The later is parent to several other classes that I intend to sync with my server.

I would like to factor a class function in `Synchronizable` that returns the object with a certain ID on the server:

```
class func withIDOnServer(_ pk:String, inMOC context:NSManagedObjectContext -> Self?
```

and use it as

```
List.withIDOnServer(pk:"1234", context)
```

The issue I have is that I cannot cast the result to the child class type. Here is my code:

```
extension Synchronizable {
// return the object with ID xxx on server. 
class func withIDOnServer(_ pk:String, inMOC context:NSManagedObjectContext) throws -> Self? {
    let entityName = String(describing: self)
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: entityName)
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"'pk' = %@", pk)
    do {
        let results = try context.fetch(request) as! [Self]
        guard results.count == 1 else {
            if results.count > 1 {
                throw fetchError.moreThanOne(pk: pk)
            }
            else { // results.count == 0
                return nil
            }
        }
        return results.first as! Self?
    }
    catch let error {
        throw fetchError.cannotFetch(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

}

The issue is the use of `Self` in the function body. (I also tried `Self?` and `type(of:self)`, no luck)
How can I return an object of the same type as the child class? Is the only way to use a Protocol (where `Self` is allowed in the function body)?

Comment: Compare [How can I create instances of managed object subclasses in a NSManagedObject Swift extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27109268/1187415)

Answer (score 2):

This is going to need Swift generics to work. Instead of `Self`, use a Swift generic type. Something like

```
extension Synchronizable {
// return the object with ID xxx on server. 
class func withIDOnServer<T:Synchronizable>(_ pk:String, inMOC context:NSManagedObjectContext) throws -> T? {
    let entityName = String(describing: self)
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: entityName)
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"'pk' = %@", pk)
    do {
        let results = try context.fetch(request) as! [T]
        guard results.count == 1 else {
            if results.count > 1 {
                throw fetchError.moreThanOne(pk: pk)
            }
            else { // results.count == 0
                return nil
            }
        }
        return results.first as! T?
    }
    catch let error {
        throw fetchError.cannotFetch(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

To get the compiler to infer the correct type, you'll need to make it clear when calling the function by declaring the type you expect. Something like

```
let myList: List? = Synchronizable.withIDOnServer("asdf", inMOC: context)
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I can even do directly `List.withIDOnServer(....)`. This is the right answer.

Comment: @harrouet, if this is the right answer, please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

If you think about it, declaring a function on your base class with a return type of `Self` doesn't make any sense. Unless subclasses override that function, calling it on a subclass is going to call the implementation of the base class and it can't magically change its return type based on which class is `self`.

Assuming that Core Data fetch request returns a `List` that is the type of object that this function should return. Can you be sure that the results of the query are all instances of `List`? If not, casting the result to `List` is at the very least unsafe.

Having got this function to return `List` or `Synchronizable`, you could consider adding a function to each subclass that does the cast to the subclass e.g. if `Foo` is a subclass, it might go like (not tested)

```
class Foo: Synchronizable 
{
    class functions getInstance(_ pk:String, inMOC context:NSManagedObjectContext) throws -> Foo? 
    {
        guard let ret = try withIDOnServer(pk, context: context) as? Foo
        else { throw MyError.classCast }
    }
    return ret
}
```