# Swift generic extension with self casting

Tags: ios, swift, generics

The goal is to dequeue cell like

```
 let cell = CustomCollectionViewCell.dequeueReusable(collectionView, for: indexPath)
```

I'm trying like

```
class func dequeueReusable<T: UICollectionViewCell>(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, for indexPath: IndexPath) -> T {
    return collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: self.reuseID, for: indexPath) as! T
}
```

But it returns UICollectionViewCell, not CustomCollectionViewCell.

How to achieve this?

Comment: `self.reuseID` cannot compile in a `class` function, so you should [edit] your question to include your actual code in the form of a [mcve]. Btw it would make more sense to define this method as an extension on `UICollectionView` and pass in the `UICollectionViewCell` subclass type as a generic input argument.

Comment: Recommend taking a look into https://github.com/AliSoftware/Reusable. It does the thing you want. (If I didn't misunderstand your question)

Comment: A protocol extension with associated type might be the better choice,

Comment: @vadian: Like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/34004264/1187415 ? :)

Comment: @MartinR Yes, something like that

Comment: Related discussion in the Swift forum: https://forums.swift.org/t/workarounds-for-self-in-classes/15754 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `dequeueReusable` never requires any particular type for `T`, so the most general is selected. The type you want, however, is `Self` (the type of the current subclass).

The natural (but slightly wrong) way to write this would be:

```
class func dequeueReusable(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
                           for indexPath: IndexPath) -> Self {
    return collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: self.reuseID,
                                                              for: indexPath) as! Self
}
```

I honestly don't know why this doesn't work. `Self` can't be used in the `as! Self` construct. It can, however, be tricked into working with a generic wrapper:

```
func cast<T>(_ value: Any) -> T { return value as! T }
```

With that, you get the working version:

```
class func dequeueReusable(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                           for indexPath: IndexPath) -> Self {
    return cast(collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: self.reuseID, 
                                                   for: indexPath))
}
```

Comment: `unsafeDowncast(..., to: self)` would be an alternative: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33200426/1187415.

Comment: Thank you; I knew there was some other solution I'd seen somewhere. And actually this is better Swift. I think this should dupe that one.