# A generic static method to create NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Let's say I have a CoreData entity called `Person`:

```swift
class Person: NSManagedObject {
    // ...
}
```

I have been trying to implement a static function `create` as an extension of `NSManagedObject`.

```swift
extension NSManagedObject {
    static func create() -> ??? {
        let object = ???
        CRUD.insertToDatabase(object) // Insert object to database
        return object
    }
}
```

Here I want `create()` to return an instance of the type from which `NSManagedObject` is inherited. For example, when I call `create()` from `Person` I want it to return a `Person` instance. When I call it from the `Animal` class it has to return an instance of type `Animal`.

```swift
let person = Person.create() // -> Returns a Person instance
let animal = Animal.create() // -> Returns an Animal instance
```

I'd appreciate any help on how to implement this kind of function in the parent class.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27109268/1187415

Comment: Hi @MartinR, your reference helped me a lot get my code working. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what your CRUD call is supposed to do since when you instantiate a NSManagedObject subclass it is automatically inserted into the context but a static method could looks like this, note that you need to send the NSManagedObjectContext since this is a static method

```
static func create<T: NSManagedObject>(in context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> T {
    let object = T(context: context)
    CRUD.insertToDatabase(object) //what happens here? Why send object?
    return object
}
```

an alternative is to let the CRUD do this directly

```
func insertToDatabase<T: NSManagedObject>() -> T {
    let object = T(context: self.mainContext)
    //save?
    return object
}
```

the first would then be called like this

```
let person = Person.create(in: someContext)
```

and the second

```
let person: Person = CRUD.insertToDatabase()
```